# querying the RESTRICT_REFERENCES pragma

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How can I programmatically find out if a package procedure is flagged with any of the RESTRICT_REFERENCES pragmas (WNDS, WDPS, RNDS...)?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I could try to call this procedure from another procedure flagged with a pragma (say WNDS) using __execute__ __immediate__, and I would get an error if the procedure in question is not WNDS. I know, it's an overkill. Any better solutions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can tell is to query the package source code, e.g.:

```
select text from all_source
where UPPER(text) like '%PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES%'
and owner = :owner
and name = :package_name
and type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Not totally reliable (this won't pick it up if the pragma definition is split across multiple lines or has an extra space or something).

Comment: Won't work at all when pragmas are specified for each subprogram (procedure of function) in the package.

Comment: @milan: actually, that's exactly what this query will give you - one row for each procedure or function. You can then parse out the name if you wish, depending on how consistent the coding style is.